# Delete or Drop All InfluxDB Databases starting with a given name

Tags: influxdb

It is possible to drop all databases in influx?
or drop only databases starting with a given prefix?

Something like:
DROP DATABASE somedb*.*

?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a short python script:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

client = InfluxDBClient(INFLUXDB_ADDRESS, 
                        INFLUXDB_PORT, 
                        INFLUXDB_USER, 
                        INFLUXDB_PASSWORD, 
                        None)
pattern='somedb'

databases = client.get_list_database()
for db in databases:
    if db.get('name').startswith(pattern):
        client.drop_database(db.get('name'))
```